# TokenError: Code was already redeemed

Tags: javascript, passport.js

I have this error when I Use passport auth. I dont know what to do

```
TokenError: Code was already redeemed.
at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/home/sambulo/Desktop/servers/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:329:12)
at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/home/sambulo/Desktop/servers/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:376:16)
at /home/sambulo/Desktop/servers/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:166:45
at /home/sambulo/Desktop/servers/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:191:18
at passBackControl (/home/sambulo/Desktop/servers/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/sambulo/Desktop/servers/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
```

Comment: Ever figure this one out? Having same issue

Comment: Please provide the code where you have your routes.